# Unable to create libcloud driver type. No CA certificates found. Google Cloud Storage and Django.

Tags: certificate, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

Attempting to configure a storage handler within Django for Google Cloud Storage.

I've installed *django-storages*, and added `storages` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I've installed *apache-libcloud*.

I've downloaded [this file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html, and appended its path to `CA_CERTS_PATH`. I'm using Mac OSX with Django 1.9 and the latest version of Google SDK. This is in my local environment.

```
 # settings.py

libcloud.security.CA_CERTS_PATH.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cacerts.pem'))

LIBCLOUD_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'type'  : 'libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE',
        'user'  : <my user, hidden here>,
        'key'   : <my key, hidden as well>,
        'bucket': <bucket name>,
    }
}
DEFAULT_LIBCLOUD_PROVIDER = 'google'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
```

[Per these docs](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/apache_libcloud.html#certifcate-authorities), I've confirmed that `CA_CERTS_PATH` *definitely includes* the cacerts.pem file.

And yet, when I run `dev_appserver.py` I am confronted with this:

```
Unable to create libcloud driver type libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE: No CA Certificates were found in CA_CERTS_PATH. For information on how to get required certificate files, please visit https://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/other/ssl-certificate-validation.html
```

What have I missed?   What is wrong with my configuration that libcloud won't work?   This is my first time setting up any custom storage configuration with Django or Google Cloud Storage.  All input is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing **curl-ca-bundle** Mac OSX port or **openssl** / **curl-ca-bundle** homebrew package (https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/ssl-certificate-validation.html)?

In theory, as long as your CA bundle file is in the correct format and the path to it is correct, your approach should work as well, but it also depends on the import order and how django-storages imports libcloud (if it imports it dynamically after you set libcloud.security setting, your setting would not have an affect).

Comment: Interesting thought.  How would I go about tracing the import order?  

Both curl-ca-bundle and openssl are the `CA_CERTS_PATH` as well..